# What is the capitol of X? Regex

Tags: python, regex

What I am trying to do is very simple, I think but I can't seem to get it to work.

My regex is:

"(?wW)hat is the Capital of (\w*?\s?\w*?)\?"

Which I am hoping will allow in things like "Russia" and "Costa Rica" to be in the capture group. Basically, I want to read in a question such as "what is the capitol of Argentina" and then be able to grab the word "Argentina" even if the sentence has a bunch of other stuff in it.

But I tried it and I entered "what is the Capital of russia?" and it said that string didn't match.

Comment: Don't you mean Capital?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I think you are looking for this](http://regex101.com/r/rO8xM5):

```
[wW]hat is the capitol of ([\w\s]*)\?
```

Your fundamental mistake is the mixing up of [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

To look for a mixture of characters (like `w` or `W`) you want to use a character class like `[wW]`.  This means when we are looking for word characters (`\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) or whitespace characters (`\s` = `[\r\n\t\f ]`), we can simple say `[\w\s]`.

The final issue would be your use of `?` and `*` ([repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)).  First of all, they have no special meaning in the character classes so I removed them. `*` repeats 0+ characters (`+` checks 1+), and `?` makes the previous key optional. This means `\w*?` is unnecessary, since it is saying optionally 0+ matches.

Note, I used a capturing group `(...)` around the capitol name meaning we can reference the capitol from capture group 1.

Finally, we can use the `i` modifier to make our matches case-insensitive..[the final expression may be simpler to understand](http://regex101.com/r/uO3yO6):

```
/what is the capitol of ([a-z ]+)\?/i
```

Comment: Will not work for Costa Rica for instance, as you stop capturing on the first space.

Comment: Nope..in the first example, I check for 0+ `[\w\s]` characters which is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_\r\n\t\f ]`. In the second example, I check for 1+ `[a-z ]` insensitively (note the space).  Try my [de](http://regex101.com/r/rO8xM5)m[os](http://regex101.com/r/uO3yO6).

Comment: You're right, sorry I didn't read it properly (I'm on mobile).

Answer (score 2):

This should match:

```
[wW]hat is the capitol of ([^?]+)\?
```

Comment: Good alternative solution, `?` is not reserved in a character class so you can use `[^?]+`.